# Java send HTTP requests concurrently and do a process with results

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I'm required to send ~100 requests HTTP requests and do some processing with the results of all HTTP requests I have sent. I want to send my HTTP requests parallelly and wait until all the results are back in order to do my process. I am quite new to Java and I'm having difficulty with the approach to this. Kindly suggest a good approach or pattern.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Http is synchronous. Only thing you can do is the processing of those 100 tasks (request) processesing (individual sending + receiving + processing) async using Future Task and executor framework on threads. Here is a example https://www.baeldung.com/java-future

Comment: [Async Rest Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425641/make-api-multiple-times-with-asyncresttemplate-and-wait-for-all-to-complete) This link maybe help for you